# Challenge For Android ImageButton background

Tags: android, xml, bitmap, scrollview, drawable

Alright so I was trying to figure this out and how no idea how to proceed
below is a ScrollView which look background is set to @drawable/patterrepeat

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="false" 
    android:background="@drawable/patternrepeat">
</ScrollView>
```

Now patternrepeat is an xml drawable that looks like this below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:src="@drawable/pattern"
    android:tileMode="repeat"/>
```

Now the src for this bitmap is a PNG image.

The challenge is how to access this "PROGRAMMATICALLY" ScrollView---->Bitmap----->Bitmap Original PNG Sources

The reason for this is that the Original Sources is Tiled to Create the Bitmap which is then loaded into the ScrollView to create the background...

How would one Proceed with this?

Comment: this will work. There is no issues. Did you get any errors?

Comment: oh i might need to mention i want to do this programmatically because i want to be able to change it on the fly base on the user preferences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// get bg drawable first
Drawable d = scrollView.getBackground();

// there are many types of drawables. In you case BitmapDrawable 
// (according to your xml) should be returned. So...
if (d instanceof BitmapDrawable) { // check drawable type just in case
    Bitmap sourceBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)d).getBitmap();
}
```

sourceBitmap is what you need.

Comment: this is very close to getting me what i want the problem is i don't know how to change the src after i obtain it? any idea how? I'm getting the src from a PNG in my drawable folder

Comment: Awe Never mind bitmap Factory... 
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.icon_resource);
a thousand upvotes to you btw thanks